# Keycloak available variables on the admin console

Tags: keycloak

I am preparing a deployment of a tool that uses Keycloak for authentication and authorization.

Multiple instances will be deployed, so I would like to automatise as much as possible the process. For this, I use a realm-export from Keycloak that I import on every instance on start up.

One of the configurations that changes is the "Valid redirect URIs" for the frontend client, since it will depend on the hostname of the deployment.

I have seen on other clients of the admin console certain variables, such as `${authBaseUrl}`, which makes me think there is probably a similar one just for the hostname of the deployment (without the `auth/` from Keycloak).

For example, for the *account* client:
[image: Account client URI configuration]

I have been searching for a while, but I am unable to find any resource listing these variables. At the very least, does anyone know which variable I could use to access the value of the `KC_HOSTNAME` environment variable?

Any help would be appreciated :)